# Pasar un string con formato Datetime a time PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Quiero pasar el contenido que tengo en un input con formato `"14/06/2016 11:17"` a time, lo he intentado con strtotime pero no me da el resultado esperado.

```
$fecha = strtotime($this->input->post("fecha"));
```

Me devuelve "0" cuando quiero que me devuelva el time de la fecha indicada.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a pasar la fecha a este formato: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss antes de usar el strtotime
El codigo de ejemplo:

```
$fechaFormateada = formatearFecha($this->input->post("fecha"));
$fecha = strtotime($fechaFormateada); 

function formatearFecha($fecha)
{
$fechaSeparada = explode(" ", $fecha);
$partesFecha = explode("/", $fechaSeparada[0]);
$nuevaFecha = $partesFecha[2] . "-" . $partesFecha[1] . "-" $partesFecha[0] . " " . $fechaSeparada[1];

return $nuevaFecha;
}
```